# What is wrong with my nested while loop for counting the element

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just want to figure out how often each element of F occurs within N and print it out. I have used the nested for loop, it works. But when I used nested while loop, it did not work as expected. I checked my code but cannot find out why.

```
F = [4,7,2]
N = [2,3,4,2,5,6,3,2,6,7,3,4]
```

**Nested for loop version, works as expected:**

```
four_count = 0
seven_count = 0
two_count = 0

for n in N:
    for f in F:
        if n == f and f == 4:
            four_count += 1
        elif n == f and f == 7:
            seven_count += 1
        elif n == f and f == 2:
            two_count += 1

print(str(F[0]) + " occurs in N " + str(four_count) + " times")
print(str(F[1]) + " occurs in N " + str(seven_count) + " times")
print(str(F[2]) + " occurs in N " + str(two_count) + " times")
```

**This is correct output:**

```
4 occurs in N 2 times
7 occurs in N 1 times
2 occurs in N 3 times
```

Nested while loop version, wrong output:

```
four_count = 0
seven_count = 0
two_count = 0

N_Count = 0
F_Count = 0

while N_Count < len(N):
    while F_Count < len(F):
        if N[N_Count] == F[F_Count] and F[F_Count] == 4:
            four_count += 1
        elif N[N_Count] == F[F_Count] and F[F_Count] == 7:
            seven_count += 1
        elif N[N_Count] == F[F_Count] and F[F_Count] == 2:
            two_count += 1
        F_Count += 1
    N_Count += 1

print(str(F[0]) + " occurs in N " + str(four_count) + " times")
print(str(F[1]) + " occurs in N " + str(seven_count) + " times")
print(str(F[2]) + " occurs in N " + str(two_count) + " times")
```

Wrong output from nested while loop:

```
4 occurs in N 0 times
7 occurs in N 0 times
2 occurs in N 1 times
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to reset `F_Count = 0` after `while N_Count < len(N):`, otherwise list `F` is only looped once. So it would be:

```
...
while N_Count < len(N):
    F_Count = 0
    while F_Count < len(F):
...
```

But unless you're learning about loops, this would not be the best way to do what you want. Something using `count` would be better, like:

```
counts = [N.count(f) for f in F]
```

or similar

Comment: you are right. Thanks. You save my day. "You have to reset F_Count = 0 after while N_Count < len(N):," Yes, I need to use nested while loop here.